# How to reoslve permission error for QR code scanning app in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to build an Android app to scan a QR code. When I click on the button `scan QR code` the app gets crashed.

Here is my code

```
    package com.example.authentix;
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

    import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
    import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 101;

        private Spinner dropdown;
        private EditText textBox;
        private Button submitButton;
        private Button scanButton;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

            dropdown = findViewById(R.id.dropdown);
            textBox = findViewById(R.id.textBox);
            submitButton = findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
            scanButton = findViewById(R.id.scanButton);

            // Populate the dropdown list
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.items_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Set click listener for the submit button
            submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String selectedValue = dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String enteredText = textBox.getText().toString();

                    // Make the POST request to the server and handle the response
                    makePostRequest(selectedValue, enteredText);
                }
            });

            // Set click listener for the scan button
            scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Check camera permission before starting QR code scanning
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        startQrCodeScanning();
                    } else {
                        requestCameraPermission();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private void makePostRequest(String selectedValue, String enteredText) {
            // Make your HTTP POST request here using libraries like Retrofit or Volley
            // Pass the selectedValue and enteredText as request parameters or in the request body
            // Handle the response from the server and display it in a popup dialog

            // For example, here we display a sample response in a popup dialog
            String response = "Sample response from server";

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Response");
            builder.setMessage(response);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Close the dialog
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }

        private void startQrCodeScanning() {
            // Initialize the QR code scanner
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
            integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }

        private void requestCameraPermission() {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST) {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Camera permission granted, start QR code scanning
                    startQrCodeScanning();
                } else {
                    // Camera permission denied, show a message or handle it accordingly
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            // Retrieve the scan result
            IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (result != null) {
                if (result.getContents() != null) {
                    // Set the scanned QR code value in the text box
                    textBox.setText(result.getContents());
                } else {
                    // Handle case when scanning is cancelled or no QR code is found
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**build.graddle (module app)**

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    }

    android {
        namespace 'com.example.authentix'
        compileSdk 33

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.authentix"
            minSdk 24
            targetSdk 33
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
    }
    //implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
    //implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
    //implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'

    dependencies {
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
        implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
        implementation ('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        }

    }
```

Here is the error I am getting in logcat.

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.authentix, PID: 24051
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat;
        at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureManager.openCameraWithPermission(CaptureManager.java:244)
        at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureManager.onResume(CaptureManager.java:233)
        at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity.onResume(CaptureActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1478)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8374)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4888)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4931)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:54)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2311)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:238)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:357)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8090)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~4pqZ2IXzRHMVB0NE2Felzw==/com.example.authentix-Ex1jXQK65vTIAQibw1Ffow==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~4pqZ2IXzRHMVB0NE2Felzw==/com.example.authentix-Ex1jXQK65vTIAQibw1Ffow==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loa
```

Comment: Take a look at this issue, it is about the exact problem you have: https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues/240